# Are all variables in js converted to objects before being executed?

Tags: javascript

From what I have understood, primitive data types such as a string can also have properties ie string can have .includes . Does that mean all primitive data types are converted to objects before being executed. If yes, what is the point of having distinct difference between primitive data types and objects.

Comment: No, they're only converted to objects when you access their properties.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you try to refer to a property of a string s, JavaScript converts the string value to an object as if by calling new String(s). This object inherits string methods and is used to resolve the property reference. Once the property has been resolved, the newly created object is discarded.
Numbers and booleans have methods for the same reason that strings do: a temporary object is created using the Number() or Boolean() constructor, and the method is resolved using that temporary object.

source `Javascript: The Definitive Guide. David Flanagan`

Answer (score 0):

When you call a property on a `string` (lower case) primitive, the JS runtime creates a new instance of a `String` (upper case) object and copies the string primitive value into the new "wrapper" object, then the property or method that you originally called gets called on the wrapper object and then that wrapper object is garbage collected when the statement is completed. This makes it only seem like some primitives have properties when they actually don't.

> If yes, what is the point of having distinct difference between
>   primitive data types and objects.

The point is that primitives are lightweight entities that have a low memory footprint, whereas Objects can do more and therefore require a larger memory footprint. Also, you can't inherit from a primitive, whereas you can from an Object.

If you'll only be doing limited Object operations, using a primitive is the best approach, but if you know that you'll be using many properties of an Object, it's  more efficient to create the Object using a constructor from the start to avoid the constant creation and destruction of wrapper objects.